# Deploy to web container, bundle web container or embed web container

Tags: java, tomcat, jetty

I am developing an application that needs to be as simple as possible to install for the end user.  While the end users will likely be experience Linux users (or sales engineers), they don't really know anything about Tomcat, Jetty, etc, nor do I think they should.

So I see 3 ways to deploy our applications.  I should also state that this is the first app that I have had to deploy that had a web interface, so I haven't really faced this question before.

First is to deploy the application into an existing web container.  Since we only deploy to Suse or RedHat this seems easy enough to do.  However, we're not big on the idea of multiple apps running in one web container.  It makes it harder to take down just one app.

The next option is to just bundle Tomcat or Jetty and have the startup/shutdown scripts launch our bundled web container.

Or 3rd, embed.. This will probably provide the same user experience as the second option.

I'm curious what others do when faced with this problem to make it as fool proof as possible on the end user.

I've almost ruled out deploying into an existing web container as we often like to set per application resource limits and CPU affinity, which I believe would affect all apps deployed into a web container/app server and not just a specific application.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  Seems bundling (or in some cases embedding) is the way to go forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deploying multiple war files (or ear files in case of full Java EE application server) was an idea that was once a promise, but in practice didn't play out very well.

A major problem is that despite major advances, hot reloading of WARs of EARs remains problematic. Memory leaks, resource leaks, class loader problems... they keep happening. The safest way to redeploy is thus to restart the whole servlet container or application server, but this takes down all other apps running on it with it.

A second problem with deploying multiple apps to a single AS is that their is only a thin layer of isolation between them. Applications can access resources in JNDI from other applications. This might not be a problem for cooperating applications, but it's really a problem for apps that are possibly hostile to each other.

In general, a servlet container is thus not a replacement for a multi-tasking, isolating operating system.

With the availability of inexpensive and efficient virtualizing products like Xen it seems to be a better option to just have one application per servlet container (indeed, bundle them) and deploy these to a Xen client.

An additional advantage of this is that it provides an easier path to upgrade the libraries on which your application depends. If you consider a fixed installation of Tomcat 6 as the deployment platform, then a single application can not just upgrade to Servlet 3.0 from Tomcat 7, since this will effect all other applications running on that same Tomcat. This is even more important for full Java EE stacks like JBoss AS, since these bundle way more libraries.

In practice this often means that with a fixed Tomcat that runs multiple apps, you can simply never upgrade your app to take advantage of newer libraries/apis offered by Tomcat, since there's always some other app that for some reason or the other can't be upgraded. This very quickly degrades into a total nightmare.

Comment: Many of the reasons you mention as disadvantages can also be advantages, depending on the situation. What you say is true if you want 100% isolation, but in many cases, the intent is to purposefully share.

Comment: Yes, if you have 'applications' that aren't really individual applications but more like *cooperating application modules*, then you indeed might want to share resources. In a way the ability to deploy multiple EARs or WARs can then be seen as an extra layering in a single app.

Comment: what would you recommend as being the smallest footprint for hosting multiple JVM's on the same hardware?

Comment: It depends on your setup. Multiple JVMs on a single OS saves you a little in some memory overhead of the extra OS', but you might have some more trouble configuring every Tomcat or JBoss AS etc to use a different port set. But memory these days is dirt-cheap so putting 8GB of memory in an entry level server is barely more expensive than say 2GB. If you host 8 XEN clients, this will give you 1GB per XEN client and some 768MB per JVM. If your app is really simply you might go as low as 64 MB per JVM and maybe 128 MB per XEN client. This will allow you to run some 64 apps on a single server.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Hudson build engine.](http://hudson-ci.org/)

It can either be deployed to an existing web container, or simply be run with "java -jar hudson.war".   For Windows it can then register itself as a service if run with administrator privileges.

It does this with the [Winstone servlet container](http://winstone.sourceforge.net/) which is designed for exactly this usage.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is not uncommon option to distribute web application together with servlet container (Tomcat or Jetty). What you gain is: total control over configuration of your web-application, end-users do not have care about configuration details. However, one of the drawbacks is the increase of the size of the installation package.